# Practical statistical course advice

Tags: mathematical-statistics, references

Can you please advise me about a good online statistical course with practical examples in R that can help me to be confident when I'm doing my analysis. I have basic to intermediate  knowledge in statistics and I want to go to advanced level.

Comment: Not online course, but maybe consider self-study from Peter Dalgaard's Springer paperback on learning statistics with R.

Comment: @BruceET, Thank you so much, you always keep helping me, I will have a look on it now. God bless you.

Answer (score 1):

I had decent stats knowledge but no practical experience with R. I subscribed to datacamp.com and it helped a lot with programming R. I really liked the interactive exercises. The focus is more on coding and applying than teaching you theory, but even so, it helped me to understand regression and other statistical concepts more fundamentally. You can try it for free but eventually you'll have to subscribe for one year. They have sales very often.